# Get available appartments

Tags: php, mysql

Appartments table:

[image: appartments table]

[image: booking:]

I want al the available appartments that are not booked.
This is my current mysql query:

```
(array) $db->getRecords('
SELECT i.id, i.num_persons, i.rating, i.lat, i.lng, i.street, i.number,
  c.title, c.introduction, c.text, c.area, c.long_term_rental, c.beds, c.features, 
  c.services_and_equipment, c.terms_and_conditions, m.url
FROM appartments AS i
INNER JOIN appartments_content AS c on c.parent_id = i.id
INNER JOIN meta AS m on m.id = c.meta_id
LEFT JOIN appartments_bookings AS b on b.appartment_id = i.id
WHERE c.language = ? 
  AND i.hidden = ? 
  AND i.publish_on <= ? 
  AND i.city_id = ? 
  AND i.num_persons >= ? 
  AND (b.arrival >= ? OR b.departure <= ?)
ORDER BY i.num_persons ASC, i.publish_on DESC
LIMIT ?, ?',

array( FRONTEND_LANGUAGE, 'N', FrontendModel::getUTCDate('Y-m-d H:i') . ':00', 
  (int) $filter['city'], (int) $filter['persons'], $filter['arrival'],
  $filter['departure'], (int) $offset, (int) $limit), 'id');
```

Comment: What is your question? What about the query isn't working?

Comment: I still get all the apartments, even when they are booked.

Comment: I have a booking records with arrival 2011-09-06 an departure 2011-09-08

If i pass a value 2011-09-07 as arrival and departure to the query the apartment still shows up.

Comment: Make sure you edit your query so that it looks nice and does not scroll of the screen and such. This makes it much more inviting for people to actually bother to answer your question. Don't just copy and paste stuff and walk of. Just this time, I've cleaned up the question for ya :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT a.id, a.num_persons, a.rating, a.lat, a.lng, a.street, a.number
  ,c.title, c.introduction, c.text, c.area, c.long_term_rental, c.beds
  , c.features ,c.services_and_equipment, c.terms_and_conditions
  , m.url
FROM appartments AS a
INNER JOIN appartments_content AS c on c.parent_id = a.id
INNER JOIN meta AS m on m.id = c.meta_id
LEFT JOIN appartments_bookings AS b 
       ON (b.appartment_id = a.id 
      AND NOT ((? > b.departure) OR (? < b.arrival)))    
     --    this ? = arrival     that ? = departure
WHERE b.id IS NULL 
  AND c.language = ? 
  AND a.hidden = ? 
  AND a.publish_on <= ? 
  AND a.city_id = ? 
  AND a.num_persons >= ? 

ORDER BY a.num_persons ASC, a.publish_on DESC
LIMIT ? OFFSET ?'
```

**Changes**

***the occupation test***
The test `NOT((param_arrival > b.departure) OR (param_departure < b.arrival))` Is a simple test for overlap, that works with 2 tests. Yours does not because it needs a total of 4 tests, so you're missing something there.
Of course this code assumes that arrival always falls before departure, so make sure you assert that assumption.

***Use an anti-join on bookings***
We put all the tests for occupation the the join criteria for the bookings.
And then I **only** select rows for with there are no bookings, i.e. for which b.id IS NULL.

***LIMIT clause***
This is just a pet-peeve of mine, but I prefer the much more intuitive `LIMIT rowcount OFFSET pagestart` syntax over the confusing `LIMIT pagestart, rowcount`.

Comment: I have a follow up question.
I need to check in the table apartments_booking (single) whether the status is not cancelled, of it is cancelled the apartment should show up in the results.


I edited the query to this: http://pastie.org/2711211 (i used pastie because the character input seems to be limited)

But now i have no results.
Any thoughts?